# Multilingual search by searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

According to [this link](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#language). We can set the language where search will happen.

My application has models with English and Russian data.

Is it possible to make search in both languages simultaneously?

Comment: Hey in the end did you find a (better) way to do that ? My website is also english/french, and prople can write text in english OR french. There's no specific field for en or fr (or I would have to reimplement a lot of things).

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris I made default language russian. Then when user saves strings I downcase them via ruby code `my_string.mb_chars.downcase.to_s` which will help for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, searchkick uses either the [`stemmer` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html) or the [`snowball` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-tokenfilter.html).

Both of those filters only accept a single value in the `language` parameter, so if you decide to specify a language, it's either one or the other.

An alternative is to use different fields for different languages (e.g. `title_en` for english and `title_ru` for russian) and apply a different analyzer and language-specific stemmer for each. You can find a detailed example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mixed-lang-fields.html).

Comment: Is it possible to swap languages in some condition?